# visual studio collapse all classes in solution

Tags: visual-studio, macros, ide, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions

in visual studio 2015 i use the [Macros for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.MacrosforVisualStudio) in order to iterate all files in solution and format (`RemoveAndSort` and `CollapsetoDefinitions`) them. recently i updated my visual studio to 2017 but i found out Macros for Visual Studio is not available yet. so i wonder is there any alternative way to format all classes in solution?

here is my scripts in Macros for Visual Studio:

```
iterateFiles();

function iterateFiles() {
    for (var i = 1; i <= dte.Solution.Projects.Count; i++) {
        iterateProjectFiles(dte.Solution.Projects.Item(i).ProjectItems);
    }
}

function iterateProjectFiles(projectItems) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= projectItems.Count; i++) {
        var file = projectItems.Item(i);

        if (file.SubProject != null) {
            formatFile(file);
            iterateProjectFiles(file.ProjectItems);
        } else if (file.ProjectItems != null && file.ProjectItems.Count > 0) {
            formatFile(file);
            iterateProjectFiles(file.ProjectItems);
        } else {
            formatFile(file);
        }
    }
}

function formatFile(file) {
    dte.ExecuteCommand("View.SolutionExplorer");
    if (file.Name.indexOf(".cs", file.Name.length - ".cs".length) !== -1) {
        file.Open();
        file.Document.Activate();

        // Format the document
        dte.ExecuteCommand("Edit.RemoveAndSort");
        dte.ExecuteCommand("Edit.CollapsetoDefinitions");


        file.Document.Save();
        file.Document.Close();
    }
}


  [1]: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.MacrosforVisualStudio
```

Comment: You could have a look at ReSharper (http://jetbrains.com/resharper) or the FormatDocumentOnSave plugin (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mynkow.FormatdocumentonSave).

Comment: thank you dear @RickvandenBosch. as far as i know ReSharper its not free. I'm gonna try FormatDocumentOnSave .

Comment: True, ReSharper is not free (although you can try it for free for 30 days). Also keep in mind that Visual Studio now supports .editorconfig files. EditorConfig helps developers define and maintain consistent coding styles between different editors and IDEs.

Comment: thanks a lot dear @RickvandenBosch. i just install the FormatDocumentOnSave  plugin but i don't know how it can iterate all files in solution and format (RemoveAndSort and CollapsetoDefinitions) them? can you help me?